# Multi level getters in symfony2/doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, getter, entities

Im wondering if theres a cleaner way to approach the system i have below, using symfony2/doctrine2.

I currently have three entities

Entity A - many to one relationship with class B, one to many with class C
Entity B - one to many relationship with class A, one to many with class C.
Entity C - Many to one relationship with class A and B.

If i do $entityA->getEntityB()->getEntityC() that will return me all the C entities assigned to entity B, but what i actually want is all the entity C entities that are assigned to both entity B and entity A. Essentially i want to recognise the getter chain, if that makes sense.

At the moment i have to pass entity A into the getEntityC method and filter out the values i dont want which is starting to get a little messy when dealing with more objects and other parts of code.

Is there a way to set this up whereby the last getter will force the relationship from both parents instead of just the immediate one?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would much recommend not to try to get value by getters, but instead create a query by DoctrineQueryBuilder and use multiple left joins. For example something like this:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GreatBundle:Entity');
$q = $repository->createQueryBuilder('e1', 'e2', 'e3')->leftJoin('e1.e2', 'e2')->leftJoin('e1.e3', 'e3');
$columns = array(
    'e1.id',
    'e2.id as e2_id',
    'c3.id as e3_id',
);
$result = $q->select($columns)->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Sorry that I didn't fully get your usage case, but you will have to recreate query just to fit it.